# Leaflet using custom event on marker clik handler

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I use leaflet 1.9.3.
I have a map with several markers with a custom icon.

when i click on a marker i change the  icon of clicked marker.

```js
const selectedIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/icones/selected.svg',
  iconSize: [22, 29], 
  iconAnchor: [15, 26],
  popupAnchor: [-3, -3]
});

marker.on('click', (event) => {
    event.target.setIcon(selectedIcon);
  });
```

This works, but when i click on another icon i want to reset the icon of the previous clicked marker.

i try to use a standard custom event (the code bellow are in function who create and return a L.Marker)

```js
marker.on(RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME, (event) => {
    marker.setIcon(selectedIcon);
  })
```

I failed to trigger the event.
if i use marker.fire( new Event( ...)); the event are just handled by the marker who emit the event.

I try many solution

event handler

```js
marker.on(RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME, (event) => {
    marker.setIcon(selectedIcon);
  })

marker.addEventListener(RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME, (event) => {
    marker.setIcon(selectedIcon);

  });
```

send event

```js
marker.on('click', (event) => {
    event.sourceTarget.getElement().dispatchEvent(createResetMarkerIconEvent());
    event.target.getElement().dispatchEvent(createResetMarkerIconEvent());
    event.target._icon.dispatchEvent(createResetMarkerIconEvent());
    event.target._map._container.dispatchEvent(createResetMarkerIconEvent());

// #carto is the div container use for leaflet map
   document.getElementById('carto').dispatchEvent(createResetMarkerIconEvent());

// this active event handler but only on the emitter of the event
   marker.fire(createResetMarkerIconEvent());
}
```

The five first are cathed py

```js
 document.addEventListener(RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME, (event) => {
    console.log('On document event listener', event);
  })
```

Factory function

```js
function createResetMarkerIconEvent() {
  console.log('New event !');
  return new Event(RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME, {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false,
    composed: true,
  });
}
```

Question : how can i retrieve this event on a maker ?

ps: I don't want to use a global array containing the markers with a foreach on it to change the icons.

Thank you for your help

Edit : example to reproduce : https://plnkr.co/edit/kPP6JiP2403ckS2D

Comment: Read https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#evented-fire - `.fire()` takes more than one parameter.

Comment: Yes, i have test it but the event are not catch in eventHandler. 

Example

```lang-js
marker.fire('RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME',{fromComponent:'test'}, true);
// or
map.fire('RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME',{fromComponent:'fromMap'}, true);
// with
  marker.on(RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME, (event) => {
    console.info('marker on custom event', event);
  });
```

the log are never display (idem with debug).

Comment: Be consistent with those single quotes around the event name/constant, buddy.

Comment: sorry, it's a copy error.

In this case ( marker.fire(RESET_MARKER_ICON_EVENT_NAME,{fromComponent:'test'}, true); ) the event is not handled by other markers. 

I have 12 makers only once handle by the emitter.

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/j63zIxSijvdgJfRu). Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hello, 
with 3 markers and fire event in 'onclick' handler you see only the log for the clicked marker. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/kPP6JiP2403ckS2D